# Is there anyway to return the Hessian matrix when using nlminb in R?

Tags: r

I would like to optimize a few parameters using `nlminb` in R, and also calculate the standard error of each parameter estimation in order to get t-value. However, `nlminb` doesn't return a Hessian matrix as other optimization commands do. Is there anyway around? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`hessian` in the numDeriv package can calculate the hessian numerically.